# In R, why is sum so slow compared to others, such as cumsum?

Tags: r, performance

I am attempting to implement a function that needs to be incredibly fast, mostly because it is working on huge data frames many times over and over.

R has always left me befuddled as to why it is sometimes a little slow, and why it is at other times ridiculously slow.  (It is unfortunately never fast.)

Regardless, I have always assumed that, when possible, things could run much faster when pushed into an apply, sapply, or lapply somehow, instead of put into a loop.  I recently ran across an example that makes me think there is something more going on under the hood that, if I were to understand it, might help me greatly with future optimizations.

Here are some calculations that I ran on my relatively powerful Ubuntu Linux machine:

```
system.time(sapply(1:1e5, sum))
user  system elapsed
35.130   0.000  35.128


system.time(sapply(1:1e5, cumsum))
user  system elapsed
0.110   0.000   0.108
```

Yes, you are reading those numbers correctly:  cumsum, which creates an array of the cumulative sum, is orders of magnitude faster than just providing me the simple sum.  (It'd be great if someone else could verify these results on their machine!)

I don't see how this is possible, except if the implementations differ drastically.  Assuming they do differ drastically, I'd like to know in what fashion, so that I could look out for certain functions to avoid when looking for speed.  (For core functions, I do not know how to see their source.  The standard means of just typing in the function name without any parentheses does not work for core functions.)

Thanks so much!

Comment: `sapply(1:5, sum)` does not make any sense really, since it will just return `1:5`. Were you looking to just sum up the numbers?

Comment: I agree it doesn't make sense, because you are doing `sum(1)` `sum(2)` etc. Also, check this out: `system.time(sapply(as.list(1:1e5), sum))` is *way* faster than w/o the `as.list`. Nonetheless, your point is interesting. Why is sum(1) slower than cumsum(1)? Also, I should point out that I did test sum(1) and cumsum(1) using microbenchmark, `sum` was 553 nanosecs, `cumsum` was 433 nanosecs.

Comment: `cumsum` and friends do not seem to have `na.rm` capabilities. I wonder if that plays into it?

Comment: Sorry @Ramnath, at first I was not performing system.time as a wrapper, and so I did not want the entire 1e5 results to show up on my screen.  I have edited my question to remove the [1:5].  But that does not affect the system.time calc.

Comment: `system.time(sapply(1:1e4, sum))` takes .15 seconds on my laptop; `system.time(sapply(1:1e5, sum))` takes 20. I wouldn't expect that

Comment: Your are mistaken in assuming that "things could run much faster when pushed into an apply, sapply, or lapply somehow, instead of put into a loop". That is simply not true. These looping functions are generally not faster than a `for` loop (provided that the latter is set up correctly, i.e., doesn't grow an object).

Comment: An amusing alternative is `sapply(1:1e5, function(x) sum(x))` which returns more or less like cumsum.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Following more or less the [instructions for using operf](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#oprofile-and-operf) I created a file with the single line `sapply(1:1e5, sum)` and ran

```
$ operf ~/bin/R-3-1-branch/bin/R -f sum.R
$ opreport -l ~/bin/R-3-1-branch/lib/libR.so |less
```

producing

```
CPU: Intel Sandy Bridge microarchitecture, speed 2.401e+06 MHz (estimated)
Counted CPU_CLK_UNHALTED events (Clock cycles when not halted) with a unit mask of 0x00 (No unit mask) count 100000
samples  %        image name               symbol name
835882   93.0929  libR.so                  RunGenCollect
27731     3.0884  libR.so                  SortNodes
9323      1.0383  libR.so                  AgeNodeAndChildren
2038      0.2270  libR.so                  CheckFinalizers
1593      0.1774  libR.so                  Rf_allocVector3
1222      0.1361  libR.so                  duplicate1
...
```

etc. Most of the time is spent in the garbage collector (`RunGenCollect` -- run the generational garbage collector). So I ran

```
$ R -d gdb R
(gdb) run
> sapply(1:1e5, sum)
^C
(gdb) break RunGenCollect
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, RunGenCollect (size_needed=50000) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/memory.c:1504
1504        bad_sexp_type_seen = 0;
(gdb) where
```

which produced

```
#0  RunGenCollect (size_needed=50000) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/memory.c:1504
#1  0x00007ffff789d354 in R_gc_internal (size_needed=50000) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/memory.c:2825
#2  0x00007ffff789e99b in Rf_allocVector3 (type=13, length=100000, allocator=0x0) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/memory.c:2563
#3  0x00007ffff788e1a5 in Rf_allocVector (type=13, length=100000) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:189
#4  0x00007ffff7831787 in duplicate1 (s=0x7ffff3b0b010, deep=TRUE) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/duplicate.c:335
#5  0x00007ffff783371a in duplicate_child (s=0x7ffff3b0b010, deep=TRUE) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/duplicate.c:199
#6  0x00007ffff783357a in duplicate_list (s=0x2c98b30, deep=TRUE) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/duplicate.c:261
#7  0x00007ffff7830fc2 in duplicate1 (s=0x2c98b30, deep=TRUE) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/duplicate.c:308
#8  0x00007ffff783371a in duplicate_child (s=0x2c98b30, deep=TRUE) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/duplicate.c:199
#9  0x00007ffff783357a in duplicate_list (s=0x2c98a88, deep=TRUE) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/duplicate.c:261
#10 0x00007ffff7830fc2 in duplicate1 (s=0x2c98a88, deep=TRUE) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/duplicate.c:308
#11 0x00007ffff7830c7f in Rf_duplicate (s=0x2c98a88) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/duplicate.c:132
#12 0x00007ffff79257f4 in do_summary (call=0x2c98a88, op=0x6259a0, args=0x303cf88, env=0x2c97f48) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/summary.c:462
...
```

and the relevant line here is line 462

```
(gdb) up 12
#12 0x00007ffff79257f4 in do_summary (call=0x2c98a88, op=0x6259a0, args=0x303cf88, env=0x2c97f48) at /home/mtmorgan/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/summary.c:462
462     PROTECT(call2 = duplicate(call));
(gdb) list
457     return ans;
458     }
459 
460     /* match to foo(..., na.rm=FALSE) */
461     PROTECT(args = fixup_NaRm(args));
462     PROTECT(call2 = duplicate(call));
463     SETCDR(call2, args);
464 
465     if (DispatchGroup("Summary", call2, op, args, env, &ans)) {
466     UNPROTECT(2);
```

The call is being duplicated

```
(gdb) call Rf_PrintValue(call)
FUN(1:100000[[5339L]], ...)
```

for each iteration of the loop, triggering garbage collection. Similar code is *not* executed for cumsum. It has been this way for a long time and for reasons that are not 100% apparent

```
$ svn annotate ~/src/R-3-1-branch/src/main/summary.c |less
...
 42643     ripley     /* match to foo(..., na.rm=FALSE) */
 42643     ripley     PROTECT(args = fixup_NaRm(args));
 42643     ripley     PROTECT(call2 = duplicate(call));
 42643     ripley     SETCDR(call2, args)
...
$ svn log -r42643
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r42643 | ripley | 2007-08-25 23:09:50 -0700 (Sat, 25 Aug 2007) | 1 line

make the rest of the group generics primitive
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It would be interesting to take this up on the [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) mailing list. It is not that `sum` is particularly slow, but rather that the calls to the garbage collector come to dominate execution time.

Hmm, on reflection it turns out that

```
sapply(1:1e5, function(x) sum(x))
```

is running in the same ballpark as `cumsum`. I think it's because the `duplicate` at line 462 in the original version is making a copy of the 1e5 elements in preparation for selecting the ith element to sum. In contrast, in `function(x) sum(x)` the vector has already been subset, so the duplication is only of the ith element. Duplicating the original vector also explains why 1e5 elements is so much slower than 1e4 elements, and why `as.list(1:1e5)` is relatively performant (only the list element is actually duplicated, or perhaps not even that). Duplication during the call to `sum` has something to do with the fact that it belongs to the (S3) `Summary` group generic, see `?"group generic"`.

Comment: On modern Intel architectures, clock cycles are not a meaningful indicator of runtime.  Instructions retired per clock cycle ranges from 4 to under 1, depending on how many execution units can be kept busy, which in turn depends on the arrangement of the code.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg would be great if you could unpack your comment a little, with maybe some pointers to better practice? Feel free to edit my response as approriate.

Comment: I'll look at `oprofile` to see if it can gather the IPC data.  Intel's VTune does, but it's quite expensive.

Comment: Part of the problem might be `lapply()`'s non-standard evaluation - it  create a new call then evaluates that. But I've never worked through `do_lapply()` closely enough to understand what it's doing.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thanks so much for the excellent details! I was expecting there was some "obvious" optimization standard practice I didn't know.  Instead, it seems I did stumble onto something real... and your explanation provided a treasure trove of excellent investigative tricks!  Thanks!

Comment: @MartinMorgan Wow... somehow I missed your last paragraph at first. I confirmed that as long as I explicitly call FUN= function(x) sum(x), it's faster.  That makes me think that perhaps things will always be faster if I explicitly call the function??  If so, that's a great nugget of info to help "optimize around" R.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson actually, this turns out to be a problem (now fixed, thanks to you, @MichaelLawrence and Prof. Ripley) in R's handling of `sum` and other Summary group generics. In R-devel on my laptop `sapply(1:1e5, sum)` now takes about 0.18s, comparable to cumsum and faster than function(x) sum(x). This doesn't seem to have been ported to the 3-1-branch, so will only appear with the next major release of R.

Answer (score 11):

Having just joined this thing, apparently I do not have enough reputation to comment on Martin's post, but I submitted a patch [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15798) to resolve the issue. Actually two patches. The first avoids duplication in almost every case. The second, much simpler patch just shallow duplicates, so that the pairlist is duplicated but not the big vector in the call. Another way to fix it would be to do the equivalent of lapply(1:1e5, function(x) sum(x)), i.e., only have the symbol in the call. However, that would interfere with do_lapply's attempt at optimization by skipping some evaluation with each iteration.

Update: the second patch has been applied to R-devel.

Comment: This is great, Michael! Presuming you keep using Stack Exchange (I like the format), you'll have plenty of rep soon.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd example since you're passing one number to `sum` each time. It is possible `sum` isn't optimized for vectors of length 1 and cumsum is. But a more logical comparison is something like

```
> system.time(sapply(1:1e4, function(x) sum(1:x)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.126   0.019   0.155 
> system.time(sapply(1:1e4, function(x) cumsum(1:x)))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.601   0.158   1.824
```

I took the range down a bit so as to avoid integer overflow.

And it's interesting how similar they are when you just some over two elements

```
> system.time(sapply(1:1e5, function(x) sum(c(1,x))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.196   0.001   0.204 
> system.time(sapply(1:1e5, function(x) cumsum(c(1,x))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.170   0.005   0.188
```

So clearly there's something going on with the `length(x)==1` case

Comment: `system.time(for (i in 1:1e5) sum(i))` takes 0.07 secs on my laptop.

Comment: OK, so clearly there's something going on with the `apply/sum` combination. Not necessarily `sum`? I should really avoid the use of the word "clearly" in situations like this.

Comment: I used microbenchmark and did 1E5 evaluations of sum(1) and of cumsum(1): median sum(1) = 458 nanoseconds, median cumsum(1) = 363 nanoseconds.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I recognized that a for loop was working more quickly in this case.  While that is also interesting in its own right, I couldn't understand this peculiarity with sapply itself.

Comment: Doing `lapply(as.list(x), sum)` runs at 0.146 seconds, which is agreeable, given that there'll be some time for `eval(.)` call from within C. Looking at `lapply` source should give an idea why it does badly when input is not already a list...